# How can I see the changes on my SQL server in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I created a new database called "staj" and imported 3 excel files into it. I edited the column names and arranged the primary keys. After that, I opened a new web form in Visual Studio and added my database to the project using Entity Framework. It was all fine until I created a new table called UserList and tried to use it in Visual Studio, it says it could not be found. I tried to update Visual Studio by going to `Tools -> SQL Server -> New Schema Comparison`.

I then got stuck because I can't get past the "Choose Source" part even though I clicked new connection and connected to my SQL Database and tested it. It said it was fine but, I simply couldn't find how to see the changes I've made to SQL in Visual Studio. Refreshing or active syncing didn't work. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**, please?

Comment: Data Source=X550-PC;Initial Catalog=staj;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole time I've been choosing the wrong keywords. My answer lies here -> [How to: Update an .edmx File when the Database Changes (Entity Data Model Tools)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx)